# Black screen instead of login screen after shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

When I switch my laptop (MSI Bravo 15) on, I see the loading screen and then it shows black screen instead of login screen. If I connect external monitor, I shows that there is no signal detected.

I have to hold the power button until laptop switches off. Then I switch it on again and it boots normally.

This happens always. I always have to boot it twice before it loads normally.

**Restart is NOT affected**. This issue happens only after I completely shut my laptop down.

The only change I can think of is that I upgraded memory from 16GB(8+8) to 32GB(16+16).

I've tried everything: update all drivers, upgrade Windows 10 to Windows 11, switch off fast boot. Nothing helps.

What are the possible reasons of that? Why can't it boot normally after normal shutdown (using OS menu) and can boot only after I switch if off by holding the power button?

**Addition #1**. I've found that it's not just display turned off / showing nothing (as I thought). It's the system not responding.

Comment: Look for error messages in the event log. And fix them.

Comment: When exactly do you connect the external Monitor? Is any other Video output device connected? What's shown in the device manager? What happens if you use a portable OS (boot from USB)?

Comment: @Albin it's connected always. But the same happens when it's not connected.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev Is any other Video output device connected? What's shown in the device manager? What happens if you use a portable OS (boot from USB)?

Comment: @Albin As I said, the problem also happens when there is nothing is connected at all. I don't have portable OS. I'll try it later.

Comment: @Albin It seems there is no official Windows Live OS. I don't want to run on my system an untrusted software...

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev Win doesn't have a "portable" Version, you will need to use a Linux distro.